# Can't find MSTest.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is mstest.exe located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375481/where-is-mstest-exe-located)

**I can run it from the Visual Studio 2010 command line tool**, but I can't find it in explorer.  Is there something else I need to install?

I've done some research, it is not where the following article says it is.. Its not ANYWHERE.

[Where is mstest.exe located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375481/where-is-mstest-exe-located)

I have Visual Studio 2010 Premium.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mine is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE.

If it's not there, download [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/), and search for mstest.exe. If you still can't find it, it isn't there. Reinstall the application.

Comment: awesome.  That was the place.  But I thought I had looked there already.  Whatever the case, Everything popped it up for me.  Apparently Windows _Search does not show you files in system directories.  Thanks!

Comment: If you're on 64-bit windows, there are folders in both Program Files and Program Files (x86) (don't ask why). That's probably why you were confused.