# Calling mstest.exe from Developer Command Prompt for VS2017 (and older)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, mstest

I used to run my build script from `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2015` which just executes `mstest.exe`. With the `Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt` however, `mstest.exe` is not available anymore. All hints from [Where is mstest.exe located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375481/where-is-mstest-exe-located) are not applicable for VS2017.

I know that it is available here: `Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe` and using following environmental variables I can access it from the dev prompt VS2017:

```
"%VCIDEInstallDir%"..\mstest
"%VSINSTALLDIR%"\Common7\IDE\mstest
"%DEVENVDIR%"..\IDE\mstest
```

But what is the recommened way to call `mstest.exe`? Which environmental variable is backwards compatible?